Doppler Shift in Moving Medium
Would the medium between a stationary source and observer moving cause a shift if the source and observer are on opposite sides of the medium?
The reason for this question is that I was noticing how ultrasound is able to observe doppler shifts in fluids within the body due to sound being reflected off of it. This made me wonder whether there is any kind of doppler shift when it comes to other radiology methods such as MRI, CT, etc. and if it is not observed because the speed of the fluid is so slow relative to the speed of the radiation (whereas sound vs fluid movement is still far apart but closer), or if there is actually just no shift as it is passing through rather than being reflected.
Another thought experiment I am having has become two:

Consider points A and B, with a laser beam pointed between them. Now there is a semiopaque block between them that is in the path of the beam but does not span the full distance between A and B. Would this block moving towards A or B cause any kind of shift?

Similar points of A and B with laser in-between, but submerged in an ideal uniform fluid. The fluid is moving though (almost like a current) towards either A or be, would this also cause any kind of shift?


While the above is for light, what would happen if these questions were applied to sound?
I sort of understand shifts when the source or the observer is moving, but this is throwing me off quite a bit. Thank you in advance!

So I am going to look at (1). The thing about relativity, is that there is no such thing as absolute motion, so you don't need to move anything. We can work in the block frame, and move the source and receiver.
So $A$ transmits a EM plane wave with $k_{\mu}$, or a photon, it doesn't matter. So: in frame $A$:
$$ k_A^{\mu} = (w_A/c, -k_A) = (k_A, -k_A)$$
Now to boost that to the block rest frame, we use $ v_A = \beta$ ($c=1$):
$$w = k = \gamma \omega_A - \beta\gamma (k_A $$
$$ k =  \gamma(k_A-\beta k_A)$$
$$ k = \gamma(1-\beta) k_A $$
$$ k = \sqrt{\frac{1-\beta}{1+\beta}}k_A $$
$$ k = f_d k_A $$
which is the traditional Doppler shift of the frequency.
The wavenumber works out to:
$$ -k = -f_d k_A $$
for
$$ k^{\mu} = f_d k_A^{\mu} $$
That propagate through the material with
$$ \omega = \omega $$
and
$$ k = k/n $$
(for a dispersion relation $\omega = \frac c n k$, which is standard index of refraction stuff).
When it returns to vacuum it is still $k^{\mu}$.
That is now received by $B$, which is also moving at $+\beta$, so:
$$ \omega_B = \gamma\omega + \beta\gamma k$$
$$ k_B = \gamma\omega + \beta\gamma k$$
$$ k_B = \sqrt{\frac{1+\beta}{1-\beta}}k $$
$$ k_B = \frac 1 {f_d} k $$
so
$$ k^{\mu}_B = \frac{k^{\mu}}{f_d}= \frac{f_dk_A^{\mu}}{f_d} = k^{\mu}_A $$
so the answer is:
NO. A stationary block of material does nothing between a source and a receiver moving at the same speed, which means:
NO: a moving block of dielectric does not change the frequency or wavelength between a source and a receiver.
